# ¿Como puedo cambiar de orden objetos de un array en JS?

Tags: javascript

Tengo declarado en mi código JS un arreglo con sus objetos. La estructura es la siguiente:

```
var quiz = [];
quiz[0] = new Question("¿Cuanto es 12+12?", "25", "24", "23", "1");
quiz[1] = new Question("¿De que color es la sangre?", "Red", "White", "Green", "2");
quiz[2] = new Question("¿De que color es el cielo?", "Blue", "White", "Green", "3");
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de recargar la página se ordene de forma aleatoria; por ejemplo:

```
var quiz = [];
quiz[0] = new Question("¿Cuanto es 12+12?", "25", "24", "23", "1");
quiz[1] = new Question("¿De que color es el cielo?", "Blue", "White", "Green", "3");
quiz[2] = new Question("¿De que color es la sangre?", "Red", "White", "Green", "2");
```

o

```
var quiz = [];
quiz[0] = new Question("¿De que color es el cielo?", "Blue", "White", "Green", "3");
quiz[1] = new Question("¿De que color es la sangre?", "Red", "White", "Green", "2");
quiz[2] = new Question("¿Cuanto es 12+12?", "25", "24", "23", "1");
```

El arreglo tiene esta estructura ya que realizo funciones adicionales.

¿existe alguna forma en la cual se pueda realizar?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es reordenar tu array de manera aleatoria. Por suerte contamos con el método `sort` que acepta una función como parámetro:

```
quiz.sort( function (a, b) {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
} );
```

Tu código debería quedar así:

```javascript
var quiz = [];

quiz[0] = new Question("¿Cuanto es 12+12?", "25", "24", "23", "1");
quiz[1] = new Question("¿De que color es el cielo?", "Blue", "White", "Green", "3");
quiz[2] = new Question("¿De que color es la sangre?", "Red", "White", "Green", "2");

quiz.sort( function (a, b) {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
} );
```

Con esto debería bastar, Saludos!

> Para más información checa aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort